# AWS Load Balancer Security Groups

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I am trying to deploy some nodejs sites with an ELB and am having some problems with the security groups for both the ELB and the EC2 instances.

What I would like to do, is allow the ELB to accept port 80 requests and forward those to port 3000 on the EC2 instances and I don't want the EC2 instances to be directly accessible from the internet, they should only be accessible (on port 3000) through the loadbalancer.

So in my VPC in my public subnets I have:

- setup an ELB that forwards 80 (HTTP) to 3000 (HTTP)

  - security group that accepts traffic inbound on port 80 from 0.0.0.0/0
- an EC2 instance that runs node on port 3000

  - security group that accepts traffic inbound on port 3000 **from the security group** of the ELB instance

This is not working. If on the EC2 instance I allow port 3000 from 0.0.0.0/0 it works.

But then I can use the instance's public IP to go to the instance **without** going through the loadbalancer.

From what I understand this should be possible or am I missing something?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what you have already, you need these:

> setup an ELB that forwards 80 (HTTP) to 3000 (HTTP)
>   security group that accepts traffic inbound on port 80 from 0.0.0.0/0

You also need to have outbound access on port 3000 from ELB to your private subnet where the EC2 instances are running.

> This is not working. If on the EC2 instance I allow port 3000 from 0.0.0.0/0 it works.

This makes me believe that your EC2 instances are running in the Public Subnet of your VPC. It should be running in side a private subnet of VPC.

Besides, Make sure that your ELB is running in the Public Subnet of your VPC.

Comment: This was one of my problems. The other part of it was discussed is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739359/ubuntu-12-04lts-on-ec2-shuts-down-after-user-data-script Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either the LB is not in the VPC or the security group that your server is in is not in the VPC.

Attaching some images below:

[image: LB Create]
[image: SG Create]